# Evolutionary explanation for the neural structures generating representations (visual subset)

Tags: perception, neurophysiology, consciousness

From my interpretation of the descriptions of individuals with specific types of brain damage (see the example in the next paragraph), it seems that in some cases part of the movie of consciousness could be missing.

In the case of [Hemispatial Neglect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemispatial_neglect) (but also many others), [and related paper](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0505332102) there may not be conscious visual experience but the remaining processing may occur, completely or partially.

A subject may not have some conscious experiences but still function in the same way than it would with it (this is a bit conjectural.)

Question

- Is there agreement on structures that would be specifically in charge of the representation of visual information (maybe the V1 as described in the paper.) ?
- Why did we evolve structures that construct a visual representation, as opposed to just operating in the dark (as in the cases cited earlier.) ?
- Could this essential structures be just a side effect of other structures ?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: [Where is the visual "image" that we "see" finally assembled?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1125/7001), and [Is there a region of cortex which over a period of development becomes the seat of self?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1117/7001).